# query taking long time to excute

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT items.itemid
FROM   billingdata
       LEFT OUTER JOIN items
                    ON items.itemid = billingdata.itemid
WHERE  billingdata.encounterid IN (SELECT encounterid
                       FROM   enc
                       WHERE  patientid = 301487
                              AND date < '2014-08-21'
                              AND enctype <> 8
                              AND deleteflag = 0)
ORDER  BY billingdata.displayindex;
```

In this query there is indexing in itemid , billingdata.encounterid,patientid.

excution plan of this query is something like this :
it's not shown any index on billingdata table.most of rows effected in this table
instead encounterid of enc table is shown in index.

it's taking aroung 18s first time.after that taking 1.8 s.but it's also slow.

what could be the solution of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding exists operate the fastest in RDBMS when looking for pure existance of something IN's are somewhat slower.

So this may be more efficient but indexes on encounterID in enc and billingdata would make a big difference.

```
SELECT DISTINCT items.itemid
FROM   billingdata
       LEFT OUTER JOIN items
                    ON items.itemid = billingdata.itemid
WHERE  exists (SELECT 1
                       FROM   enc
                       WHERE  patientid = 301487
                              AND date < '2014-08-21'
                              AND enctype <> 8
                              AND deleteflag = 0
                  AND enc.encounterID = billingdata.encounterid)
ORDER  BY billingdata.displayindex;
```

or even a join can be faster depending on indexes..

```
SELECT DISTINCT items.itemid
FROM   billingdata
INNER JOIN enc
   ON ENC.EncounterID = BillingData.EncounterID    
  AND patientid = 301487
  AND date < '2014-08-21'
  AND enctype <> 8
  AND deleteflag = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN items
   ON items.itemid = billingdata.itemid
ORDER  BY billingdata.displayindex;
```

Comment: now it's taking .2 second.thanks.second query works.